# How IIS Server works(threading)

Tags: asp.net, multithreading, iis, threadpool

I have a question about processing new user(by IIS server), who start work with ASP.NET Web-application. What happens with threads pool when new user connect? Does the IIS server allocate a new thread for each user? Are there any limits for number of threads? I would be grateful for information about it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HTTP has no notion of users or sessions, neither has IIS. Both think in terms of requests.

In ASP.NET incoming requests are put into a queue and worked on by thread-pool tasks.

Open keep-alive connections do not consume threading resources. IIS manages them in the Windows kernel using async IO.

ASP.NET has a limit how many requests it will queue. This limit is quite high. The thread-pool is the standard .NET thread-pool and all its limits apply as well. Normally, you don't have to worry about these limits.

Comment: thx for response! And how thread-pool tasks executes, if their number is large? For example, if at one moment server recieve 1000 http requests, executing of each of them takes 10 seconds, what happens? they would executed in parallel threads, or one after one consequentially? (I intrested in this because I want to make my global static structures thread-safety in my application).

Comment: They are executed concurrently. You should probably not have any global mutable data structures. Web apps should be stateless because they can be killed at any time (server reboot, ...). And for high availability you probably need two web servers which do not communicate.